# Trying to set up environment for php on mac, the file does not exist

Tags: php, apache

Hi I am about to learn PHP and setting up and environment to use it. It should already be install on mac and i just need to activate it. when i type the command

```
sudo open -a TextEdit /etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

it says it does not exist. If anybody can help point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you navigated to the `/etc/httpd` folder on your system and verified that the file is there? Also what is the _exact_ error message you receive?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Yes, it says that /etc/httpd doesnt exist either. there is no error message just 'this file does not exist".

Comment: etc/httpd would be a folder not a file. I didn't mean try to open it with your text editor, I meant to try to go to it in your file explorer (sorry I don't know what the Mac equivalent of windows explorer / nautilus is called - is it Finder?) and see if the folder actually exists and contains the file you're looking for. A simple visual check.

Comment: `there is no error message just 'this file does not exist`... That _is_ the error message. It's just always better for clarity if you paste error messages exactly rather than paraphrasing them :-)

Comment: Ah sorry yes, I'm still learning, i will do for next time!  I'm in the folder and the file doesnt exist, i guess I just have to make the file and put in some boiler plate text?

Comment: Why would you do that? Why do you need this file, and why are you modifying it by hand? BTW httpd.conf is an Apache file, not a PHP file. Did you install Apache? Did you check where Apache stores its config files in a Mac environment? It may or may not be the same as where it stores them in a Linux/Unix environment (I don't know if maybe you're following a Linux-based tutorial or something)

Comment: I was following the mac setup here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_installation_mac.htm

Comment: when i followed the first command it gave me this error. "httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message"

Comment: i googled the error and it led me to this page to set server name https://zxtech.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/how-to-configure-servername-directive-globally-for-apache-http-server/

Comment: its on step 1 of this i was trying to access the config file that doesnt exist

Comment: That's just a warning because you're running on a local machine, which obviously doesn't have its own domain name. So it's using your local IP address instead as the address of the webserver. As it says, you can suppress the warning if you like. It has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: Anyway that seems to be a very old tutorial because it's talking about installing PHP 5, which isn't even supported any more. And the previous page (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_environment.htm) is talking about Windows NT/2000/XP. So it's probably 15-20 years out of date! If you're just starting out you need to be starting with 8.0, or failing that 7.4, which are the only supported versions of PHP currently (see https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.packages.php

Comment: ah brilliant, thanks for the help, installing with brew now